# how to install node-mongodb-native with nodejs in windows

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I use **nodejs** and **mongoose** to save document to **mongodb** in windows in development, but I fail to connect to **mongodb**.  My nodeunit test is always being blocked to the line `mongoose.connect()`.

I found **mongoose** use **node-mongodb-native**. My question is：

1. Do I need to do some special instructions to install node-mongodb-native in windows 7 (64-bit)?
2. How to install **node-mongodb-native** in windows?

Comment: Where there errors when you installed mongoose via `npm`? As you can see, it has a dependency on the driver so it should have installed automatically: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/package.json

Comment: And, what do you mean that the connection was blocked? Is MongoDb running?

Comment: I will check it and feedback soon. thx

Comment: My nodeunit test is wrong, after i corret it, mongoose can connect mongodb server. thx.

Comment: Actually, I still don't know if my mongodb or mongoose use **node-mongodb-native**? and how to enable it with my mongoose for performance?

Comment: It's the same thing. The `mongodb` npm package is `node-mongodb-native`. Look at the package file linked above for more information.

Comment: I added a full answer with the explanation of how to validate that mongoose is using `node-mongodb-native`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Mongoose has a dependency on the npm package `monogodb`.
2. If you look at the npm page for mongodb here, https://npmjs.org/package/mongodb, you'll find the homepage form the package is http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/
3. That page is node-mongodb-native.

So, there's nothing you need to do special to get it, as doing

```
npm install mongoose
```

is enough to install the native package.